# How to obtain a list of running emacs servers from a shell?

Tags: emacs, emacs-server

I want to write a script that "links" an emacs server to a certain directory.
To do so I need to check all existing servers to be sure if a server with a specific name is running or not. Then the script can decide to start a new server, or not, before opening a file from that directory using emacsclient.

I have been looking around to find out how to list the existing emacs running servers, unsuccessfully though.

Is there anything like `emacs --list-servers` that I could use?

Cheers.

Comment: Could you potentially just use emacs' --eval options to evaluate elisp from the command line, such as inspecting the server-clients variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs stores the socket files for all running servers in `${TMPDIR}/emacs$(id -u)`, where `$TMPDIR` defaults to `/tmp` if unset.  Find all running servers is as simple as listing all sockets in that directory.

In Bash, this would look roughly like

```bsh
local serverdir="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/emacs${UID}"
local -a servers
for file in ${serverdir}/*; do
  if [[ -S ${file} ]]; then
    servers+=("${file##*/}")  
  fi
done

echo "${servers[@]}"
```

The `servers` array now contains the names of all running Emacs servers, for use with `emacslcient -s`.

**Edit:**  Since you're using Python apparently, the same in Python:

```py
import os
from stat import S_ISSOCK

serverdir = os.path.join(os.environ.get('TMPDIR', '/tmp'),
                         'emacs{0}'.format(os.geteuid()))
servers = [s for s in os.listdir(serverdir)
           if S_ISSOCK(os.stat(os.path.join(serverdir, s)).st_mode)]
```

Comment: Very smooth! I got a solution in python checking the emacs running processes containing "--daemon=" as argument. But this one works way better! Cheers

Comment: @mrcl You're welcome :) By the way, don't rely on the Emacs command line.  Most stuff given on the command line can be changed later on from within Emacs.  For instance, a user can explicitly start a server with `M-x server-start`, even without `--daemon`.  In fact, that's how I start my Emacs server (I don't use `--daemon`).

Comment: @mrcl I added a Python example as well, for the sake of completeness :)

Comment: Nice, I was wondering... Is there any way to check if those sockets are necessarily from the servers? I mean, what if other emacs extension is running and use the same protocol, creating sockets in the this /tmp/emacs${UID} folder?

Comment: The `server-socket-dir` variable is of import here. That's not necessarily `/tmp`, and your own config might affect it of course. You might use `socketdir=$(emacs --batch -l server --eval "(princ server-socket-dir)")`, but then that's still only going to work for Emacs instances using that same value (which may or may not be fine/reliable for you).

Comment: You might also then use `lsof` to show the processes using the socket files.

Comment: @mrcl I don't think that any other extension would write to this directory.  If it did, it conflict with Emacs server regardless, because `emacsclient` assumes any socket in this directory to be a Emacs server socket.  So I don't think that you need to take this into account in your script.

Comment: @phils `server-socket-dir` is a `defvar`, not a `defcustom`.  As such, I don't think that it's intended to be changed.  Actually, I'm pretty sure that changing the variable would actually break `emacsclient`, because the value of this variable is hardcoded in `emacsclient` (didn't try, though).  Given this, I don't think that you actually need to look at the real value of the variable.  Just taking its hardcoded value, as my answer does, should be sufficient.

Comment: Well I would think it should be a `defconst` if it's not intended to be changed. There's nothing wrong with changing a `defvar`. I agree that the hard-coded approach should be fine, though (as either approach is still making assumptions).

Comment: @phils Good point. There are probably cases in which it's changed from Lisp, but let's say it's not intended to be changed by the user in their customizations.

Answer (score 1):

If i didnt misunderstood you, you could just use emacsclient -a emacs. This will start emacs if a emacs server is not running else open emacsclient and connect.